# How many bits are in the address field for a directly mapped cache?

Tags: memory, cpu, computer-architecture, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

Here is the problem I am working on: 
**The Problem:** " A high speed workstation has 64 bit words and 64 bit addresses with address resolution at the byte level. Assuming a direct mapped cache with 8192 64 byte lines, how many bits are in each of the following address fields for the cache?  1) byte 2) Index 3) Tag?"

First I defined the terms in this problem and used the other Stack Overflow Direct Mapped Cache question and my other question on [Caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30552938/how-many-words-can-be-in-the-address-space) as references(Please correct me if any of my definitions are wrong)

- 64 bit words - processor can process 64 bits at a time
- 64 bit addresses w byte level addressing - there are 2^64 memory locations in RAM and each memory location stores a byte.

  [Cache](http://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/~ghosh/4-1-10.pdf) is high speed and is partitioned into cache lines

  [Directly Mapped Cache](http://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/~ghosh/4-1-10.pdf) is where a RAM memory block is mapped into one cache line(not sure of the significance of this

Now working off [Direct Mapped Cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15937002/how-does-direct-mapped-cache-work) as a reference

1. Byte - Because a byte line is made up of 64 bytes, you need 6 bits to indentify a single byte within that byte line
2. Index- Because there are 8192 "rows" of byte lines, you need at least 10 bits to identify every row

Now heres the part of where I am stuck. The other  [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15937002/how-does-direct-mapped-cache-work) said "All the other bits are TAG bits." while this lecture [post](http://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/~ghosh/4-1-10.pdf) said "Each line has a tag that indicates the address in M from which the line has been copied". I am guessing that M means the RAM.

So here, all the other bits would be 64 - 6 - 10 = 48 bits. But wouldn't you need all 64 bits in the TAG to indicate what memory location in the RAM the data in the cache came from? Can someone clarify the confusion I have here?

Comment: How big is the cache in this question?
(Note that e.g. a 256KB cache would imply 18 bits somewhere in your calculations :)).

Comment: Did I get the other two parts right? Because each cache line has 64 bytes and there 8192 of them, the cache is made up of 524288 bytes. To identify one byte, you need 19 bits. So tag is only 3 bits?? That seems way too small to identify which block of RAM the cache line came from